# Indexing array with operations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, indexing

I am looking for a way to create an indexing array that includes operations on some entries.

For example, I have a set of points and I want to extract the first, the second and the first minus the second point.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])

magic_idx_array = [0, 1, [0]-[1]]

print(p[magic_idx_array])
```

This gives me an error but, I expect:

```
array([1.1, 2.2, -1.1])
```

I know I could use a function here, but, I would like to keep it simple an quick.

Comment: what error dod you get?  Do you understand it?

Comment: [0] - [1]  is an unsupported operand type. I understand and I expected it. I know it is wrong, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative that works with slicing.

Comment: `[0]+[1]` 'works' but produces `[0,1]`  `[0]` is a list, and the operator is applied to it, not 'saved' for the array indexing in the next line.  And no, there isn't any  way with array indexing to express math between the selected elements.

Comment: I haven't seen this kind of request before, and am not entirely sure what you are trying to avoid.  Python indexing selects elements; doing math on those elements is a separate step.  `numpy` indexing is complicated as it is, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is syntactically wrong:

you should do:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])

[p[0], p[1], p[0]-p[1]]

#output
[1.1, 2.2, -1.1]
```

or

```
np.array([p[0], p[1], p[0]-p[1]])

#output
array([ 1.1,  2.2, -1.1])
```

Comment: I know that it is wrong, but I don't want to save the result in an array but the operation instruction as it will be applied on different arrays. I could define a function: p_new = lambda p: np.array([p[0], p[1], p[0]-p[1]]). But I need to slice this object as well, which is why I need it as an array. An array of lambda functions could be a solution but that seems bloated.

Comment: What does `[0]-[1]` signify ?                                                                                                
Is it just `-1` (negative one) or it is the `first element - second element` ?                     
First and Second element of what ?                                                                                  
So it should be `p[0] - p[1]` which means First element of `array p` minus Second element of `array p`. Hope it clarifies....

Comment: As mentioned in the text: I want to extract the first, the second and the first minus the second point. In reality I have much larger nested arrays. I was mainly interested if the concept of slicing can be combined with simple operations somehow. So if p = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, ...] that p[something] gives [1.1, 2.2, -1.1]. Does this 'something' exist? Or do I have to do some_function(p) to get [1.1, 2.2, -1.1]